# how to update the values while iterating dictionary items?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, enumeration

I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, long> Reps = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

and I want to update the values while iterating through all items, like this:

```
foreach (string key in Reps.keys)
{
    Reps[key] = 0;
}
```

it is giving me an error saying:

```
"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"
```

can anyone tell me why it is giving me this error, because I have one more function that adds the value, and it is called when button is clicked:

```
public static void Increment(string RepId, int amount)
{
     long _value = Convert.ToInt64(Reps[RepId]);
     _value = _value + amount;
     Reps[RepId] = _value;
}
```

and this function is working fine. so whats the problem when updating all the values? And whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

more simplified, do this:

```
foreach (string key in Reps.keys.ToList())
{
    Reps[key] = 0;
}
```

and the reason for the error is you are trying to edit the actual object which is in use and if you make a copy of it and then use it like this:

```
var repscopy = Reps;
foreach (string key in repscopy.keys)
    {
        Reps[key] = 0;
    }
```

it'll give the same error as it also pointing to the original object, and when the ToList() is added it created a new object of List

Answer (score 4):

The problem is no updating the values, you just cannot change the collection that your foreach() is based on while the foreach is being iterated.

Try somehting like this

```
List<string> keylist = Reps.keys.ToList();
foreach(string r in keylist) 
{
Reps[r] = 0;
}
```

this would work.

Comment: its wokring but you have answered only one part of my question i.e. the solution ... can you explain more about whats the reason of the error?

Comment: Well, i guess because the foreach is based on the collection, and if you would change the collection how can the foreach determine what parts are left to process and what not? E.g. if you would add a new Reps[x] during the iteration would you expect it to participate in the foreach or not?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are changing the element in the `Dictionary<string, long>` while looping over it with `foreach`. Try this.

```
foreach (string key in Reps.Keys.ToList())
{
    Reps[key] = 0;
}
```

Now you are looping over a list created from the dictionarys key. As it is not the original collection thats modified, the error will go away.